# Redux's mapStateToProps not mapping props between AngularJS and React

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Our project is mainly written in AngularJS 1.5, but we are transitioning over to ReactJS. We're using [react2angular](https://github.com/coatue-oss/react2angular) to allow our AngularJS project to consume React components. Our project is also using `ngRedux` to store certain data. While I'm able to save certain data using Angular, I am unable to access the Redux store data via the mapped props.

`this.props.interval` in `CardController.js` is undefined. I am able to get store data using `this.props.store.getState()`, but React is not able to detect if there has been a change in the Redux store in `componentWillReceiveProps`, so I don't think that's an option.

### CardContainer.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import CardController from './CardController';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    interval: state.interval
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = null;

const ScorecardContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(CardController);

export default CardContainer;
```

### CardController.js

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Card from './Card';

export default class CardController extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selected: this.props.interval,
      state: this.props.$scope.filterParams,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="CardController">
        <Card
          selected={this.state.selected}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

CardController.propTypes = {
  interval: PropTypes.string,
};
```

### reducers.js

```
import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes';

const initialState = {
  interval : 'week'
};

export const setInterval = (state, action) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    interval : action.interval
  };
};

export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.SET_INTERVAL :
      return setInterval(state, action);
    default :
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're keeping `props.interval` in the component's local state? The way this code is structured now, it doesn't make sense to use it, you could just use the `this.props.interval` in the render function in place of `this.state.selected` and omit the need for local state altogether. The whole point of redux is to move internal state of components to a global redux state. There might still be cases where you might want to use local state, but this doesn't look like one. BTW, the `setInterval` function is already defined on the window, overriding it seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Good point. I was keeping `props.interval` in the local state since I was thinking about the controller component being responsible for state management for its child (and this was before I started working on Redux). But yeah, there's no need for `this.state.selected`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the problem was that I forgot to drill down. Instead of `state.interval`, it should have been `state.card.interval`.